# Can I transfer and view xvid (avi) videos on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, applications, video, mediaplayer

What type of video files can I watch on my iPad?

I usually only have `.avi` files; is there an app that will allow me to play them?

Comment: I rephrased your question, also, if you want to ask a question about Cydia, please ask another separate question (after searching if it wasn't already asked)

Answer (score 4):

You could also try AirVideo, which will convert and stream xvid (and other formats) from a local PC.

You can connect to it via local network or remotely as well.

http://www.inmethod.com/air-video/index.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use [**OPlayer HD**](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/oplayer-hd/id373236724?mt=8) to watch your video on your iPad. There's also a [free ad-supported version](http://itunes.apple.com/fr/app/oplayerhd-lite/id385896088?mt=8) available

Answer (score 0):

I usually use [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/) to convert everything to .mp4 or .m4v (iTunes-friendly extension) before importing it to iTunes and syncing it to an iDevice.  Just open it up and give it a source file, pick the proper preset, and press Go.

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is converting your videos using [Macroplant's Adapter](http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/). Quite simple to do.

Answer (score -2):

Use [VLC for the iPad](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/vlc-media-player/id390885556?mt=8) (link is directly to the apple store for VLC)

Quicky guide through [here](http://lifehacker.com/#!5643124/getting-the-most-out-of-vlc-for-ipad)

Comment: VLC is no longer on the App Store